# json no imprime consulta de datos JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp

Cordial saludo

Buenas tardes

estoy trabajando en un proyecto para hacer una prueba de consulta usan json pero cuando voy a imprimir para ver la consulta en json no sale nada como se muestra a continuación

[image: no sale nada en la consulta]

si revisamos la consola en respuesta no sale nada
[image: no aparece nada ni siquiera el la impresion en json que deberia estar aqui]

el codigo utilizado es el siguiente

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
 HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         Connection con =null;
         Conexion cn = new Conexion();
         Statement st = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         
         try{
             String sql="SELECT Id_estudiante,Name_users,Mail_users,Phone_users,Estado_usuario,Id_campus,Id_program,Semestre,Modalidad,Documento
 FROM estudiantes;";
             con=cn.getConexion();
             st=con.createStatement();
             rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
             String datos="";
             com.google.gson.JsonObject gson= new JsonObject();
             JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
             while(rs.next()){
                 JsonObject item = new JsonObject();
                 item.addProperty("Id",rs.getString("Id_estudiante"));
                 item.addProperty("Nombre",rs.getString("Name_users"));
                 item.addProperty("Mail",rs.getString("Mail_users"));
                 item.addProperty("Phone",rs.getString("Phone_users"));
                 item.addProperty("Estado",rs.getString("Estado_usuario"));
                 item.addProperty("Campus",rs.getString("Id_campus"));
                 item.addProperty("Faculty",rs.getString("Id_faculty"));
                 item.addProperty("Program",rs.getString("Id_program"));
                 item.addProperty("Semestre",rs.getString("Semestre"));
                 item.addProperty("Modalidad",rs.getString("Modalidad"));
                 item.addProperty("Documento",rs.getString("Documento"));
                 //datos +=rs.getString(1)+""+rs.getString(2)+""+rs.getString(3)+""+rs.getString(4)+""+rs.getString(5)+"\n";
                 array.add(item);
             }
             gson.add("datos", array);
             out.print(gson.toString());
         }
         catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ListarEstudiantes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
 null, ex);
         }        finally{
             out.close();
         }
     }
```

cuando imprimo usando datos como se muestra el codigo que esta comentado si me retorna los datos en mi base de datos pero implementando json no y tampoco nada en la consola me retorna de la siguiente manera
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

```js
 
 <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 
                 var tabla=$('#estudiantes').DataTable({
                      ajax:{
                      method:"POST",
                      url:"ListarEstudiantes",
                      dataSrc:"datos"
                      
                 },columns:[
                     {"data":"Id"},
                     {"data":"Nombre"},
                     {"data":"Mail"},
                     {"data":"Phone"},
                     {"data":"Estado"},
                     {"data":"Campus"},
                     {"data":"Faculty"},
                     {"data":"Program"},
                     {"data":"Semestre"},
                     {"data":"Modalidad"},
                     {"data":"Documento"}
                     
                 ]
                 });
                
             });
         </script>
 
>
```